# ListBox1.SelectedIndex ArguementOutofRange Error c# Windows Fors

Tags: exception, listbox, outofrangeexception, listbox-control

Please some body help me with my codes i am getting ArguementOutofRange Exception again & again. Please tell me what am i doing wrong. I tried every loop for this but it always gives ArgueOutofrange Error.

Exception is:-

"InvelidArguement = value of '3' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex"

&

Warning is:

"The result of the exception is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'"

this is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.Items.Add("www.google.com");
        listBox1.Items.Add("www.facebook.com");
        listBox1.Items.Add("www.yahoo.com");
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listBox1.DataSource = listBox1.Items;

        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var num = listBox1.Items.Count;
        string str = Convert.ToString(num);
        textBox1.Text = str;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; )
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var num = listBox1.Items.Count;
        string str = Convert.ToString(num);
        textBox1.Text = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do yourself a favor and look into `BackgroundWorker` instead of `DoEvents`.  `DoEvents is just wrong.

You really haven't given us much to go on other than dumping a few dozens lines of code in a question and ask people to figure out where the problem is and fix it.  **Where the exception** occurs is common courtesy if you want people **to help you**.

The issue is *probaably* at the line that assigns `SelectedIndex` in `button1_Click`.  If all items are sucessful in the browser, you're going to set the selected index to 3 and the highest valid index is 2.

Comment: Exception is:-

"InvelidArguement = value of '3' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'. Parameter name: SelectedIndex"

&

Warning is:

"The result of the exception is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'"

Comment: i am still getting the same Exception & if i am using for (int i = 0; i < num; ) for it then why it's go to index 3. i used while(listbox1.SelectedIndex < num) loop for it put it always go for index 3